# Return value of each key in object in a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

I have an object and an array:

```
m = { "1": ["2", "3"], "6": ["4", "5"] };
var p = ["1", "6"];
```

I have a for loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
    // Return an array that is the value of a key in m, for each key specified in p
    var array = m[p[i]]; 

    // do stuff with array
}
```

Any reason why the above does not work? array is still `undefined` after the for loop runs.

Comment: `m = { "1": ["2", "3"], "6", ["4", "5"] };` this is invalid json, you have `"6", ["4", "5"]` without a keys. maybe you mean this `m = [{ "1":["2", "3"]}, "6", ["4", "5"]];`

Comment: @samy.vilar: No one said it was JSON, but you're right about the `"6"`. The object syntax is invalid. I'm guessing it's a typo in the question.

Comment: @amnotiam JSON stands for Javascript Object Notation, what is he doing? declaring an object. (I think, I have no idea actually since its wrong)

Comment: @samy.vilar: He's using object literal notation to create a JavaScript object. This is not the same as JSON. If JSON is embedded in JavaScript code, it must be done as a string, since JSON is textual data.

Comment: @amnotiam `this is invalid json` I should have just stuck out and said this is invalid JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your declaration of  `m = { "1": ["2", "3"], "6", ["4", "5"] };` gives syntax error for me. I assume you mean `m = { "1": ["2", "3"], "6": ["4", "5"] };`.

`p.length` is 2, so you have 2 iterations of the loop. In first iteration values of your expressions are:

```
i = 0
p[i] = "1"
m[p[i]] = m["1"] = ["2", "3"]
```

In second loop:

```
i = 1
p[i] = "2"
m[p[i]] = m["2"] (undefined)
```

You have only `m["1"]` and `m["6"]`, no `m["2"]`. That's why `array` is undefined in the last iteration. So it remains undefined after the loop.

You may correct `m` declaration as following:

```
m = { "1": ["2", "3"], "2": ["4", "5"] };
```

Now you will get `array = ["4", "5"]` after the loop.

I can advise you not to store integers in strings. Use `2` instead of `"2"`. Otherwise it can cause errors in the future. For example, `2 + 2 = 4` and `"2" + "2" = "22"`. If you have `"2"` from some other code, use `parseInt` to convert it to a normal number.

Also, you don't have to create `p` variable with list of keys. You can simply use `for..in` loop to iterate through keys of your object:

```
m = { 1: [2, 3], 2: [4, 5] };
for(i in m) {
  var array = m[i];
  //do stuff
}
```

Keep in mind that `for..in` doesn't guarantee to preserve the order of keys. However, all existing implementations of `for..in` do preserve the order.

Comment: Thank you, especially for the tip about `for (i in m)`. The reason the keys are integers are because I'm using them as ids, and the ids won't necessarily be integers. I probably should have used something like `a` and `b` for the keys in the example.

Comment: Keep in mind that `for-in` doesn't guarantee an order. If you need to enforce a specific order, the Array technique used in the question should be used.

Comment: Using integer as an object key is OK. I was speaking about `["2", "3"]`, it should be `[2, 3]`.

Answer (score 2):

Also I think `p` should be `[1,6]` as well? Since you're using it to reference the keys in the object `m`.

Comment: +1, the error is that the loop ends with `array = m["2"]`, which is undefined, since `m` has no key `2`.

Answer (score 1):

The error happens because you have this declaration:

```
var p = ["1","2"];
```

But the `m` properties are:

```
m = {
    "1": [2,3],
    "6": [4,5]
}
```

So in `p[1]` makes your program read `m["2"]` but it doesn't have a "2" property.
Use this code instead:

```
var p = ["1","6"];
```

Comment: Probably wouldn't put quotes around the properties of the object, either.

Comment: @MarkLinus: All object properties are strings, including Array properties.

Comment: @MarkLinus Sometimes putting quotes around properties of objects can have unwanted side effects, hence, you probably shouldn't if you don't have to.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: Can you provide an example of that?

Comment: @amnotiam you are right. The script is not crashing because of what I said. It was and error on the p var

Comment: @amnotiam Let me rephrase that, I generally consider it bad practice because it's perfectly acceptable to use a reserved word as an object property name in quotations, such as "for" or "in".  What if the quotations were to be deleted later on?  Could be a disaster.  There are advantages to using quotations, but I haven't ran into a situation where it would help me.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: So you're actually saying it's a bad practice to use keywords or other non-valid identifiers as properties, since that would be the actual issue if the quotations were deleted. That's fine, but in actuality, it is perfectly valid to use keywords as properties, but for some lingering non-compliant implementations that had issues in the past. Doing `({if:'else'}).if` is valid code.

Comment: @amnotiam Never said it wasn't valid to use keywords as property names, but, you probably shouldn't.  Thus, I don't use quotations if I can help it.

Comment: @SethenMaleno: Oh, alright. Then I misinterpreted your statement *"...acceptable to use a reserved word as an object property name in quotations.... What if the quotations were to be deleted later on?"* I thought you meant that reserved words required quotations.